# Background process shows as "not responding" on OS X

Tags: macos, node.js, cocoa, background-process, activity-monitor

I'm attempting to resolve this weird problem with our OS X application.

As part of it's normal operation, it starts a long running background process — specifically a Web server, written in node.js.

After some time running, the background process shows up in the activity monitor as "Not Responding".

[image]

It's still functioning normally though, responding to requests from the web browser and not eating a high percentage of CPU or anything.

I would like to understand what exactly might be causing this status to be displayed, since it's not even a GUI application in the first place. What exactly does OS X use to determine  if a command line application is not responding, if it doesn't have a Cocoa event loop?

Is it possible to flag it somehow as a background process so that the system does not query it for responses?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Just checked, the same seems to happen when launching the task from the command line. What makes a background app "Not respond" on the activity monitor?

Comment: I think this has to do with your usage of node.js.
Command line tools do not seem to trigger the "app not responding" notification even when hogging a full core for a long time. Try it by running a simple C app which executes an infinite loop.
In the end, you need to provide more info about what you are doing...

Comment: That was indeed the case. It was a node-specific functionality, `process.title`, that was causing the process to be displayed as "not responding". Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so as [sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671858/sergio) pointed out in his comment, it was indeed something specific to Node.JS.

The dev responsible for Node.JS portion of our app was able to trace back the source of the problem to the usage of the `process.title` property in Node.JS.

It looks like [the implementation of `process.title` in libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/d48168afd0453d6258c527d71ac058c7b98ce13d/src/unix/darwin-proctitle.c#L54-L165)  does a lot of Core Foundation tricks to set the process title, so these are probably getting the process flagged as a GUI app by whatever heuristics the Activity Monitor uses to tell Cocoa apps apart from CLI apps.

We have filed a [bug report](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/966) on libuv about this, but for now we're skipping `process.title` as simply setting it causes the server to show up as "not responding" on the Activity Monitor after a couple minutes.

**Update:** This is now fixed in libuv as of [this commit](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/commit/08e0e63f3adecafeacaf09f519587c381c6e2ef2). It still hasn't propagated to a node release yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's Process Manager Reference](http://www.filibeto.org/unix/macos/lib/dev/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/process_mgr_ref.pdf), `GetCurrentProcess`, `GetFrontProcess` (et al.) are  deprecated in OS X 10.9 and causes the "not responding" issue in Activity Monitor (my observation).